# usercontrol wpf static memory

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I'm new to WPF and coming from a C++ background so maybe I'm worry about memory management too much here.

Anyways, I've got a UserControl (NewContact) that has a grid with 2 columns, upper column displays 3 radio buttons and depending on which is selected it loads the appropriate UserControl into the lower section of the grid.

```
private void newMilitaryContactRadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl NMC = new NewMilitaryContact();
        NewContactWindowGridDisplay.Children.Insert(1, NMC);
    }

    private void newMilitaryContactRadioButton_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NewContactWindowGridDisplay.Children.RemoveAt(1);
    }

    private void newLegalContactRadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl NLC = new NewLegalContact();
        NewContactWindowGridDisplay.Children.Insert(1, NLC);
    }

    private void newLegalContactRadioButton_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NewContactWindowGridDisplay.Children.RemoveAt(1);
    }

    private void newFirmContactRadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl NFC = new NewFirmContact();
        NewContactWindowGridDisplay.Children.Insert(1, NFC);
    }

    private void newFirmContactRadioButton_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NewContactWindowGridDisplay.Children.RemoveAt(1);
    }
```

Now my question is whether I should be, and how to, unload the UserControls I create, when a radio button is unchecked.  I did some searching around MSDN documentation and saw that the using the remove method from the parent object would unload the usercontrol.  If that is the case is the code I'm using to in the various "unchecked" methods correct so as not to pile up a ton of NFC/NLC/NMC UserControl objects if someone were to click amongst the three radio buttons over and over and over again?

Much thanks to anyone to who can explain this to me :)

Comment: Just a suggestion, wouldn't it be easier to create 3 controls at the start-up and then bind their `Visibility` to appropriate radio buttons? That way only one would be shown at the time, but there would be no creation of objects involved on change. :)

Comment: That would make a lot of sense actually...I've been thinking about this too hard it seems.

Comment: :) Still, it's just a suggestion, but if you were to do it that way and had any problems, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to read more about .Net memory management and know how it works. In your case it depends on what your UserControls are doing? If they are using system resources it will good to dispose their references in `UserControl` `unloaded` events, otherwise `GC` will take care of them.

Read this article :
[Garbage Collection: Automatic Memory Management in the Microsoft .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx)

Also the way you are going is not so good, because soon you will find out you need to do more with your UserControl like setting its `DataContext`, `Style`s handling events and etc... and this will hard to do with code.